# Checking two IEnumerables for equality

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a helper method which would check whether two `IEnumerable<T>` collections are equal in terms of the sequence of elements and items within the sequence. I have come up with a solution below which functionally seems to do the job. I was wondering if there is perhaps a more efficient way to perform this sort of comparison between two `IEnumerable<T>` collections that is more clear and concise.

```
    private static bool AreEnumerablesEqual<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        var firstList = first.ToList();
        var secondList = second.ToList();

        foreach (var item in firstList)
        {
            var itemIndex = firstList.IndexOf(item);
            if (!item.Equals(secondList[itemIndex]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: So [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) then?

Comment: `ToList` creates a new list even if the sequence passed is already one. You just need to try-cast to `IList<T>`(to include arrays) with the `as` operator. If the casts succeeds there is no need to create and fill a new collection. **2nd**:  Don't use `foreach` and `IndexOf` if you already have a list, you can access via index. Use a `for`-loop instead.

Comment: If you have `ToList` then for sure it can be improved performance wise. If you want to implement your own method instead of `SequenceEqual` then use iterators and iterate while both still have a next item plus items are equal

Comment: `IndexOf` is a bad idea if you have something like `new [] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` which would match `new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal(v=vs.110).aspx)?

You have two options.

1. Using `T`'s default equality comparer:

   ```
   public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(
       this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
       IEnumerable<TSource> second
   ```
2. Using a specific `IEqualityComparer<T>`; useful when you need specific equality logic the type `T` doesn't provide or you are using some legacy code that makes use of `Equals(object other)` and entails boxing (`T` is a value type).

   ```
   public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(
       this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
       IEnumerable<TSource> second,
       IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer
   ```

Comment: Good answer, but could probably do with a bit of an example

Comment: @Jaxi Do you *really* think that the author of this question doesn't know how to call a method?  You apparently have a really low opinion of their ability.

Comment: @Servy I meant in a case of it risking being flagged as a low quality answer.

Comment: @Jaxi Editing in irrelevant information to a post makes it *worse*, not *better*.

Comment: @Servy They've added additional information about the answer, it won't just be the OP that will read the answer in the long run, it will be a range of people with a range of different experience.

Comment: @Jaxi So do you think those other people reading the question later aren't going to know how to call a method?